# Longest alphabetical sentence

Tags: open-ended, english

What is the longest alphabetized (by first letter) sentence you can construct?

For example, consider these "words":

> be, a, fish, elephant, crashed, dead

If this were a sentence, it would be valid:

> A be crashed dead elephant fish

The sentence doesn't have to be logical, but it must be a sentence. Example of an illogical sentence:

> The fish walked over the air

If you run out of 26 words somehow, you may start over at `A` yet again, but no reusing words.

Comment: http://wordcounter.net/ may help with counting your words/word reuse

Comment: Unfortunately, contests like this one seem to devolve into ones of stretching what it means to be a sentence.

Comment: Do the words just have to be in alphabetical order, or do they have to start with successive letters like your example does?

Answer (score 6):

I've got one at **26+26=52 words**

> Any blue crown does encompass fatter grey helmets in just kings' lovely mild noses, opening paths, quickly reaping short things underneath violent winds, xeroxing yelling zebras and brown candied diapers entirely filled, grossly helping it, juicing kind, light, minced navel oranges, purposely queuing rinds, slowly tenderizing uncovered violas with xerotic yellow zippers.

Comment: What is xeroxing?

Comment: Photocopying. (Xerox sold the first photocopiers.)

Answer (score 0):

> After birth cardinals destroy envelopes for glorious hats.

I know it isn't that good, but I didn't look in dictionaries to temporarily know some new words.